# Base64 vs NSPropertyListSerialization

Tags: ios, nsstring, uiimage, base64

I need to encode my image into text. 
And I found this class for that:
[Base64 for iOS with ARC](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64)

When I try to encode my image I see that `NSPropertyListSerialization` creates absolutely the same string as base64 does. Is it the right way to create base64 String with `NSPropertyListSerialization` or am I missing something?

Base64:

```
[data base64EncodedString];
```

NSPropertyListSerialization:

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[[NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:data format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:nil] bytes]]
```

Answer (score 1):

No you're not missing anything. Base64 is simply a standard from encoding binary data in ASCII and pLists use Base64 encoding for encoding binary data like images (using NSPropertyListSerialization) so they should create identical Base64 strings for the same binary data.

If you're wondering about which to use in your application I'd recommend you use the base64 library. While Apple has pushed to make pLists a standard and pLists will probably always encode binary data as Base64 in future, in the extremely unlikely event they change something or drop support for pLists your code will break. Besides it's best to be clear in your code (for yourself and others) that you're encode your data to base 64.